# iOS: full page interstitial ad shows black screen after close

Tags: ios, xcode, iad, interstitial

I show a full screen advertisement with this code, which works showing a full page advertisement.  The problem is that when I close the advertisement I just have a blank screen.  It does not show my app anymore.

My code:

```
-(void)showFullScreenAd {
    if (requestingAd == NO) {
        interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
        interstitial.delegate = self;
        self.interstitialPresentationPolicy = ADInterstitialPresentationPolicyManual;
        [self requestInterstitialAdPresentation];
        NSLog(@"interstitialAdREQUEST");
        requestingAd = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: there has to be a better solution to this? im having the same issue now!

Comment: well the solution I posted has been working for me, please post an answer if you find a better solution to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.  I just needed to present my view controller again when the advertisement had been closed.  I used the following code:

```
-(void)interstitialAdActionDidFinish:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd {
    interstitial = nil;
    requestingAd = NO;
    NSLog(@"interstitialAdDidFINISH");

    // present my view controller again
    ViewController *myVC = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:myVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Comment: I posted a comment about this very issue at http://stackoverflow.com/a/31790963/455791. In short, it's better to present the ad in a new UIViewController and then dismiss that view controller once the ad finishes.